# How do I create this circle pattern in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

This is what I want to create.

[image]

---

This is what I've created so far.
[image]

Now I don't know how to merge 6 circles like above.
Any ideas, Please?

Comment: For starters: rotate the clone of original three-circle image 60 degrees around the center

Comment: The shapes are in the [Foil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foil_(architecture)) family.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Select the overlapping shapes and use `Divide` in the `Pathfinder` palette to chop the shapes into pieces:
[image]

That will look something like this:
[image]

Then select the appropriate pieces and use `Unite` in the `Pathfinder` palette to recombine them like this:
[image]

Answer (score 17):

You can't really have solid shapes like that overlapping above and below different parts of the same shape. What I normally do is simply duplicate the shape. You then have one for the "behind" parts and one for the "in front" parts, and delete, mask or otherwise hide the appropriate areas...

So you start with two shapes like this:

[image]

Duplicate the bottom shape, bring it to the front then simply delete (or mask or whatever) everything except the areas that need to overlap:

[image]

Repeat the process for the next shape:

[image]

[image]